# Why does adding a string to an Object change the type to a string?

Tags: java

Say I have the following code

```
URI uri = URI.create("https://example.com");

String myString = uri + "/something"; // why is this allowed and compiler doesnt complain?
```

I would have thought compiler would complain about adding a string to URI type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String myString = uri + "/something"; 

// why is this allowed and compiler doesnt complain?
```

There are two meanings for `+` in Java: numeric addition and string concatenation; see [Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

The string concatenation meaning is adopted if one or both of the operand expressions is a `String`.  In that case, the *other* operand is converted to a string by calling `toString()` on it.  Therefore ...

```
String myString = uri + "/something";
```

means the almost<sup>1</sup> the same thing as:

```
String myString = uri.toString().concat("/something");
```

---

<sup>1 - There is some special case handling for `null` ...</sup>

Answer (score 2):

JVM calls the object's toString() method.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I wasn't sure if it was a runtime or compiler thing.